# How to test angular $compile result?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I write simplified test to research how can I test compiled directives.
But I can't make it work:

```
    fit('debug compile', function(){
        var el = compile('<div></div>')(scope);

        backend.expectGET('/index.tpl');

        scope.name = 'World';
        scope.$digest();

        http.get('/index.tpl').success(function(html){
            expect(html).toBe('<h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>'); //ok
            var compiled = compile(html)(scope);
            expect(scope.name).toBe('World'); // ok
            expect(compiled.text()).toBe('Hello, World!'); // Expected 'Hello, {{name}}!' to be 'Hello, World!'
        });
        backend.flush();
    });
```

What happened here: `$http` receives correct template from `$httpBackend`.
But when I compile it with `$compile` it rendered without scope substitutions.

How achieve correct behavior here?

As you can see, scope variables not substitute here.
I tried to add `scope.$digest` after compile, but it gives me another error `digest in progress`.
I assume, this from `$http` `scope.$apply` call.

Comment: Do not test $compile this is not part of your code. The angular team already test it. Test your code behavior.

Comment: Really, I need to test one of my providers, that uses `$compile`. and for understand what's happened just move this part of provider code to test directly.

Comment: I don't test `$compile` itself. I just want it to work after `$http` request in my tests.

Comment: Note that in order to compile the template you have to insert it in the application ` element.html(value);$compile(element.contents())(scope);` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is not asynchronous code, unwrap the promise

```
var html;
http.get('/index.tpl').then(function(result){
    html = result;
});
backend.flush();
```

And only then

```
        var compiled = compile(html)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        expect(scope.name).toBe('World');
        expect(compiled.text()).toBe('Hello, World!');
```

`$http` is redundant and doesn't have to be here at all, unless you wish to test Angular service (and you most probably don't).

Comment: I have my own provider, which download template(with `$http`), then compile it. I just want to test it. And I investigate just now(in the angular.js ngInclude directive tests), about `backend.flush`. It is what I looking for. Earlier was `$apply/$applyAsync` call and tests works.  [Here](https://github.com/thorn0/angular.js/commit/305dd5d9441561b35a325f465c70d57dae437b31#diff-748e0a1e1a7db3458d5f95d59d7e16c9L1271) is a link to break change.

Comment: @vp_arth Not sure about breaking change, this PR hasn't been merged yet.

Comment: Agreed, my research become too wide :)

Comment: Only now I understand, that `$http` is synchronous byself, `$httpBackend` make it to be async. And when we use it mocked with `MockXhr`, it becomes sync too.

Comment: The whole thing is synchronous with flush(), i.e. you don't have to use Jasmine async features in Angular specs.

Answer (score 1):

I Created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Raulucco/pen/mevwPw?editors=101) with a directive test:

```
  it('assigns "anonimous" to the name', function() {
    var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var $el = $compile('<div test-dir></div>')(scope);
    $scope.$digest();
    expect($el.text()).toBe("Hello anonymous");
  });
```

Comment: It covers another case.

Comment: Also, codepen ability to share jasmine testflow is cool. But your environment has many to setup yet. Tests failed with `StackOverflow` :) `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Angular was tried to load twice. Chrome Content-Security Policy was violated. Too many errors in my chrome...

Comment: wierd, the angular script was duplicated and the ng-mocks too. When i linked it here it was working ... no should be fixed

Comment: all other scripts doubled too. Anyway initial question not about this primitive(It is [documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing)) case. Anyway, thanks ;)